# What approach should i use when making tab bar application

Tags: ios, iphone, cocoa-touch

I'm started to work at new place as iOS programmer. I joined existing project and got an assignment that i don't really know how to approach.

So my problem is this: when you press a button, next window has to have a tab bar with four icons, this means four different navigation stacks. Its not that hard to make, but in main screen i have more then four icons, and if i press any one of them next window always has to have a tab bar with four static icons, like shortcuts or something.

So what should I do? Does anyone had the same situation? I want to start with a good advice to save trouble later on.

Answer (score 1):

You should probably rethink the app design. Tapping an item on the tab bar shouldn't result in a different number of tab bar items, as it leads to an unstable and unpredictable UI.

While not the most efficient in terms of visible content, you could introduce a segmented control (or a similar custom view) on top right under the navigation bar (if there is one), as seen in the Facebook app (though here it is used to perform actions, not changing views).

Comment: I think u missunderstood my question. First app view is just a simple view without a tab bar, just few buttons layed out on the screen. It looks just laike a modal view without navigation bar or a tab bar. When you press one of the buttons, i present other view witch has a tab bar with four main buttons. But main view has 6 of them and my boss wants that u could reach only four of those from the tab bar. And i dont think this is a good idea because if u press button that is not in the tab bar, the navigation will be terrible. So i want to know if this is even possible and how to simplify this.

Comment: I still don't get what "main view" and "other view" is. Is it that you "should" have 6 tab bar items, but you boss only wants to have 4 and the other two somewhere else? This doesn't sound like a good idea.

Answer (score 0):

Your root view controller should be embedded in a navigation controller. Then push a view controller which contains any number of tab bar items **not** TabBarController. Then you can present each view controller either push or custom.